# Convert a RDF to SVG, in python or javascript?

Tags: python, svg, rdf

Does anyone have code which convert a RDF into a SVG, ideally in python or javascript.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think your question is too vague and overly broad to be answered here on SO; see the [FAQ#dontask]. If you have more concrete problems (preferably involving some code), feel free to ask those!

Comment: just want to know if anyone know any library or someone already done so, if it is ok

Comment: Fwiw, I don't find this question too vague, really, but to make it more explicit: I assume the intent of the OP is to render an RDF file as a graph, using SVG. Makes perfect sense to want to do that, I think it's a legit question. I don't have the answer for you, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the libraries rdflib and pysvg could be of use for your work.

http://codeboje.de/pysvg/

http://code.google.com/p/rdflib/